# make_pair:error C2665: no overloaded function could convert all the argument types

Tags: c++

An exercise on C++ primer：Write a program to read a sequence of **string**s and **int**s,storing each into a **pair**.Store the pairs in a **vector**.

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<pair<string, int>> v;
    string word, i;
    while (cin >> word >> i)
        v.push_back(make_pair( word, i ));
    
    return 0;
}
```

It reports:

> error C2665:
> 'std::vectorstd::pair<std::string,int,std::allocatorstd::pair<std::string,int>>::push_back':
> no overloaded function could convert all the argument types

Can someone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: If that book is recommending `using namespace std;`, it's the wrong book.

Comment: no need to use `make_pair` here. `v.push_back({word,i});` (after fixing the problem addressed in the answer)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Or even `v.emplace_back (word, i);`

Comment: `i` is a `string`, not a `int`, as required by your `vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string word, i;
```

You define the variable `i` as a `std::string`, when you're supposed to define it as an `int`:

```
std::string word;
int i;
```

---

With the current code, the call

```
make_pair( word, i )
```

is the same as

```
make_pair<std::string, std::string>( word, i )
```

There's no automatic conversion anywhere from `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` (create by your `make_pair` call) to a `std::pair<std::string, int>`. The two types are just not the same and not compatible in any way.